# How to install Matlab Compiler Runtime on Linux

Tags: matlab, installation

I am trying to install the MATLAB Runtime (see [www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr)) on Ubuntu.

I think what I did is right before it tell me to set environment variables, others need to set two variables such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `XAPPLRESDIR`, but when I install MCR , the config information only tell me to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Has anyone out there successfully installed MATLAB Runtime(R2017b (9.3)) on Ubuntu? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include which steps you took to install the runtime, and what you see after (e.g. what errors you see when trying to use a MATLAB compiles executable).

Comment: have you solved your problem? Share your result? :D